# the argument `var.equal=TRUE or FALSE` in 't.test()' function

Tags: r

When will I use the argument `var.equal=TRUE` or  `var.equal=FALSE` ?

i haven't understood by reading the r documentation file.

Could you give me practical example to make it clear to me the situation of var.equal=TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: I recommend brushing up on what a t-test is and the assumptions it makes.

Answer (score 7):

I have been a statistician for years and I advocate always using `var.equal=FALSE`.

As you know, the T-test is a test for differences in means between two groups. By the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the sampling distribution of that statistic is asymptotically normal. Approximating the variance of the limiting normal distribution of the sample difference in means for finite sample sizes requires an estimate of the effective degrees of freedom to correct for the joint estimation of the standard deviation $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ of the two groups along with the mean difference $\mu_d$.

Assuming that these variances are equal simplifies estimation but can egregiously miscalibrate the test when they are in fact different. The mild gains in power you get from simpler estimation are pretty much negligible for any modest sized $n$. So for that I say you never set the variances in groups to be equal.

Comment: Why should one not just test for variance homogeneity (e.g. using `car::levenTest`) and decide on basis of the result how to set `var.equal`?

Comment: @Beasterfield Two reasons. 1) Unequal variance tests are still correct when the variances are in fact equal. 2) This introduces multiple testing issues and the p-value of the final analysis can't be interpreted in the same way.